# How do I can I use the array.push() method, so I can push data from one component into an array in a seperate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component (Task.jsx) that recieves text data from the user, and that data needs to be pushed into an array, which is in it's own file (TaskData.js). How do I get get the input text pushed into the array? Not sure how to get the two files to talk to each other. Code as follows:

TaskData.js

```
const TaskData = [
    {
        id:8,
        chore: 'wash dishes'
    },
    {
        id:9,
        chore: 'do laundry'
    },
    {
        id:10,
        chore: 'clean bathroom'
    }

]

export default TaskData
```

Tasks.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import TaskData from './TaskData.js'


class Tasks extends React.Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            updatedTask: '',
            isEditing: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

handleClick () {
    TaskData.push({id:50, chore: 'test'})
        this.setState({
            isEditing:true
        })
      }

handleChange (e) {
    this.setState({
        updatedTask: e.target.value
    })
}



    render() {
    return (
        <div className = 'tasks-container'>
            <div>
                {
                this.state.isEditing ?
                <input onChange = {this.handleChange} className = 'input' placeholder ={this.props.task}/>
                : <h1 className = 'font'>{this.props.task}</h1>  
                }
        <button onClick = {this.handleClick} className ='task-button'>Edit</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    }
    
}

export default Tasks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since react runs in the browser, you cannot write data into file. (You can read files though).

Note that in your `handleClick` when you do `TaskData.push(...)` you have mutated the array and you will have the updated data in the `memory` until you refresh the page. So you can use the `TaskData` variable access the updated data.

If you specifically want to write data to file, you can [store it in localStorage](https://medium.com/@siobhanpmahoney/local-storage-in-a-react-single-page-application-34ba30fc977d) or you can [save file on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449406/write-to-a-text-or-json-file-in-react-with-node).