# Write to a text or JSON file - react - node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I'm referring to this [post (Write to a text or JSON file in react with node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449406/write-to-a-text-or-json-file-in-react-with-node).

I got the exact problem so I tried out the solutions. I don't understand the solutions very well. I spent a lot of time doing by trial and errors. For example, in this solution:

```
const handleSaveToPC = jsonData => {
  const fileData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
  const blob = new Blob([fileData], {type: "text/plain"});
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'filename.json';
  link.href = url;
  link.click();
}
```

Where should I put this code? The variable "handleSaveToPC" is declared but not used. How should I use it? I show my App.js and index.js files below. My goal is to write the contactsData array to a local json or text file. I do appreciate if anyone guide me exactly what I have to do. Thank you so much.

App.js

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import AddContactForm from "./forms/AddContactForm";
import EditContactForm from "./forms/EditContactForm";
import ContactTable from "./tables/ContactTable";

const App = () => {

  const contactsData = [
    { id: 1, organization: "A Ltd.", name: "Carol", email: "carol@gmail.com" },
    { id: 2, organization: "B Ltd.", name: "Paul", email: "paul@gmail.com" },
    { id: 3, organization: "C Ltd.", name: "Emily", email: "emily@gmail.com" }
  ];
  
  const initialFormState = { id: null, organization: "", name: "", email: "" };

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(contactsData);
  const [currentContact, setCurrentContact] = useState(initialFormState);
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);

  const addContact = (contact) => {
    contact.id = contacts.length + 1;
    setContacts([...contacts, contact]);
  };

  const deleteContact = (id) => {
    setEditing(false);
    setContacts(contacts.filter((contact) => contact.id !== id));
  };

  const editRow = (contact) => {
    setEditing(true);
    setCurrentContact({
      id: contact.id,
      organization: contact.organization,
      name: contact.name,
      email: contact.email
    });
  };

  const updateContact = (id, updatedContact) => {
    setEditing(false);
    setContacts(
      contacts.map((contact) => (contact.id === id ? updatedContact : contact))
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Address Book</h1>
      <div className="flex-row">
        <div className="flex-large">
          {editing ? (
            <Fragment>
              <h2>Edit contact</h2>
              <EditContactForm
                editing={editing}
                setEditing={setEditing}
                currentContact={currentContact}
                updateContact={updateContact}
              />
            </Fragment>
          ) : (
            <Fragment>
              <h2>Add contact</h2>
              <AddContactForm addContact={addContact} />
            </Fragment>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="flex-large">
          <h2>View contacts</h2>
          <ContactTable
            contacts={contacts}
            editRow={editRow}
            deleteContact={deleteContact}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As you're trying to download a file through the frontend, you're able to use your function pretty much anywhere. Just add for example a button, like this:

`<button onClick={handleSaveToPC}>download</button>`

and change your function to:

```
const handleSaveToPC = () => {
  const fileData = JSON.stringify(contactsData);
  const blob = new Blob([fileData], {type: "text/plain"});
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = 'filename.json';
  link.href = url;
  link.click();
}
```

**Original answer:**

I suppose you're using React for the frontend and node for the backend. If so, you could send the data to a backend route, and there write the data to the PC with this function.

I'd suggest using [fs](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp).

This is an example function for how you could do it.

```js
const fs = require('fs')

const writeToJSON = (data) => {
  const DATA_PATH = '/path/to/file'
  fs.writeFile(
    DATA_PATH,
    JSON.stringify(data),
    (err) => {
      if (err) return console.error(err)
      console.log('Wrote data to ', DATA_PATH)
    },
  )
}
```

Comment: Should I write above codes in App.js? Variable 'writeToJSON' is declared but not used. Where should I use it? Thank you.

Comment: No, fs only works in node. Have you set up axios or any post methods to send information to your backend?